# Permission denied Error after deploying to Openshift using JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, openshift

We have an application that needs to communicate with some governmental web services using a SSL connection.

When running on develop environment (locally) it works perfectly, but when we deploy to OpenShift ant try to run the same task the problem comes out and show a big error StackTrace, which we can say that the problem is specif from OpenShift:

```
10:00:29,286 WARN  [org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.StAXDialectDetector] (http--127.2.25.1-8080-6) Unable to determine dialect of the StAX implementation at jar:file:/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-modules.jar!/
10:00:33,146 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] (http--127.2.25.1-8080-6) I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when processing request: Permission denied
10:00:33,148 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] (http--127.2.25.1-8080-6) Retrying request
10:00:33,214 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] (http--127.2.25.1-8080-6) I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when processing request: Permission denied
10:00:33,216 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] (http--127.2.25.1-8080-6) Retrying request
10:00:33,219 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] (http--127.2.25.1-8080-6) I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when processing request: Permission denied
10:00:33,220 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] (http--127.2.25.1-8080-6) Retrying request
10:00:33,223 INFO  [org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender] (http--127.2.25.1-8080-6) Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://homologacao.nfe.fazenda.sp.gov.br/cteWEB/services/cteRecepcao.asmx]: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.net.Socket.bind(Socket.java:631) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.bind(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:114) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bind(SSLSocketImpl.java:65) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at br.com.ps.transp.util.cte.HSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(HSProtocolSocketFactory.java:91) [classes:]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346) [commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:560) [axis2-transport-http-1.5.3.jar:]
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199) [axis2-transport-http-1.5.3.jar:]
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:76) [axis2-transport-http-1.5.3.jar:]
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:400) [axis2-transport-http-1.5.3.jar:]
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:225) [axis2-transport-http-1.5.3.jar:]
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:438) [axis2-kernel-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402) [axis2-kernel-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229) [axis2-kernel-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165) [axis2-kernel-1.5.3.jar:1.5.3]
        at br.inf.portalfiscal.www.cte.wsdl.cterecepcao.CteRecepcaoStub.cteRecepcaoLote(CteRecepcaoStub.java:196) [classes:]
        at br.com.ps.transp.util.cte.Transmissor.enviarCte(Transmissor.java:119) [classes:]
        at br.com.ps.transp.mb.ConhecimentoMB.transmitirCte(ConhecimentoMB.java:913) [classes:]
        at br.com.ps.transp.mb.ConhecimentoMB$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.transmitirCte(ConhecimentoMB$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
        at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:66) [log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar:2.0-rc1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
```

We have a class to register the communication protocol before doing the action, as following:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509KeyManager;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ProtocolSocketFactory;

import br.com.ps.transp.util.Const;

public class HSProtocolSocketFactory implements ProtocolSocketFactory {

    private static final String TRUSTSTORE = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
    private SSLContext ssl = null;
    private X509Certificate certificate;
    private PrivateKey privateKey;

    public HSProtocolSocketFactory(X509Certificate certificate, PrivateKey privateKey) {
        this.certificate = certificate;
        this.privateKey = privateKey;
    }

    private SSLContext createSSLContext() {
        try {
            KeyManager[] keyManagers = createKeyManagers();
            TrustManager[] trustManagers = createTrustManagers();
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);

            return sslContext;
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(HSProtocolSocketFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(HSProtocolSocketFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(HSProtocolSocketFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(HSProtocolSocketFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(HSProtocolSocketFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private SSLContext getSSLContext() {
        if (ssl == null) {
            ssl = createSSLContext();
        }
        return ssl;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort, HttpConnectionParams params)
            throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {
        if (params == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameters may not be null");
        }
        int timeout = params.getConnectionTimeout();
        SocketFactory socketfactory = getSSLContext().getSocketFactory();
        if (timeout == 0) {
            return socketfactory.createSocket(host, port, localAddress, localPort);
        }

        Socket socket = socketfactory.createSocket();
        SocketAddress localaddr = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort);
        SocketAddress remoteaddr = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        socket.bind(localaddr);
        try {
            socket.connect(remoteaddr, timeout);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Logger.getLogger(HSProtocolSocketFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, t);
            throw new ConnectTimeoutException("Connection timeout error", t);
        }

        return socket;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress clientHost, int clientPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(host, port, clientHost, clientPort);
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(host, port);
    }

    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    public KeyManager[] createKeyManagers() {
        HSKeyManager keyManager = new HSKeyManager(certificate, privateKey);

        return new KeyManager[] { keyManager };
    }

    public TrustManager[] createTrustManagers() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        char[] senhaTrustStore = Const.SENHA_CACERTS.toCharArray();
        InputStream inputCacerts = null;

        inputCacerts = new FileInputStream(TRUSTSTORE);
        trustStore.load(inputCacerts, senhaTrustStore);
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
        return trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
    }

    class HSKeyManager implements X509KeyManager {

        private X509Certificate certificate;
        private PrivateKey privateKey;

        public HSKeyManager(X509Certificate certificate, PrivateKey privateKey) {
            this.certificate = certificate;
            this.privateKey = privateKey;
        }

        public String chooseClientAlias(String[] arg0, Principal[] arg1, Socket arg2) {
            return certificate.getIssuerDN().getName();
        }

        public String chooseServerAlias(String arg0, Principal[] arg1, Socket arg2) {
            return null;
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String arg0) {
            return new X509Certificate[] { certificate };
        }

        public String[] getClientAliases(String arg0, Principal[] arg1) {
            return new String[] { certificate.getIssuerDN().getName() };
        }

        public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String arg0) {
            return privateKey;
        }

        public String[] getServerAliases(String arg0, Principal[] arg1) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Before do the communication we call:

```
Protocol protocol = new Protocol("https", new HSProtocolSocketFactory(x509Certificate, privateKey), 443);
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", protocol);
```

We have seen lots of posts saying about binding ports on OpenShift but nothing is clearly explained.

**Again I say, locally it is transmitting and receiving exactly as expected.**

**Anyone has any idea what could we do to solve this problem?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What local port did you specify on your call to `createSocket`?  The `java.net.BindException: Permission denied` error usually means you tried to bind to a low port (<1024) without root privileges.

Comment: Yes, that is what I heard and read on lots of posts, actually I did not specify any local port (as you can see in the code). Do you think I should? Where exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the default `SocketFactory` tries to bind to `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1`.

You must ensure that httpclient uses a protocol socket factory which does not explicitly bind to the client side interface.

See the discussion and the proposed solution here: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/commons-httpclient-permission-denied

Comment: Thanks for answering, I saw that discussion and it is exactly the last question (which remains with no answer) that is my problem. They talked about a solution to port 80 and in my case is to a secure port.

Answer (score 1):

You must ensure that httpclient uses a protocol socket factory which does not explicitly bind to the client side interface.

This is not 100% true, when making an connection you bind to a client side socket. The trick is to bind to a non restricted port. The is usually handles this for you when you request a client side socket.

My guess here is that openshift is either blocking the port your trying to bind to (because your not letting the is give you an open port), the socket factory should let you make out going connections.

It also possible but less likely that, selinux is blocking you, to keep you from delivering a DOS attack from openshifts servers.