# Google Maps API is not working on Openshift

Tags: java, google-maps, openshift

I am using Google Maps API for my application. When it makes a call to Google Maps API server, I am getting “Permission Denied” error. It seems that there may be proxy settings required to be supplied to the call.

**Advanced Geocoder Class**

```java
public class AdvancedGeoCoder extends Geocoder {
    private HttpClient httpClient;

    public AdvancedGeoCoder(final HttpClient httpClient) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public AdvancedGeoCoder() {
        this(new HttpClient(new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager()));
    }

    public AdvancedGeoCoder(String proxyHost, int proxyPort, int timeout) {
        super();
        this.httpClient = new HttpClient(new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager());
        httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(proxyHost, proxyPort);
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.SO_TIMEOUT, 60 * timeout);
    }
    public AdvancedGeoCoder(final String clientId, final String clientKey) throws InvalidKeyException {
        super(clientId, clientKey);
        httpClient = new HttpClient(new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager());
    }

    public AdvancedGeoCoder(final HttpClient httpClient, final String clientId, final String clientKey) throws InvalidKeyException {
        super(clientId, clientKey);
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    protected GeocodeResponse request(final Gson gson, final String urlString) throws IOException {
        final GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(urlString);
        try {
            httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
            final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream(), getMethod.getResponseCharSet());

            return gson.fromJson(reader, GeocodeResponse.class);
        } finally {
            getMethod.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

**Geocoder class**

```java
public class Geocoder {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Geocoder.class);

    private static final String GEOCODE_REQUEST_HOST = "maps.googleapis.com";
    private static final String GEOCODE_REQUEST_SERVER_HTTP = "http://" + GEOCODE_REQUEST_HOST;
    private static final String GEOCODE_REQUEST_SERVER_HTTPS = "https://" + GEOCODE_REQUEST_HOST;
    private static final String GEOCODE_REQUEST_QUERY_BASIC = "/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false";
    private static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";

    private final String clientId;
    private final Mac mac;
    private String serverKey;

    public String getServerKey() {
        return serverKey;
    }

    public void setServerKey(String serverKey) {
        this.serverKey = serverKey;
    }

    public Geocoder() {
        clientId = null;
        mac = null;
    }

    public Geocoder(final String clientId, final String clientKey) throws InvalidKeyException {
        if (clientId == null || clientId.length() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ClientId is not defined");
        }
        if (clientKey == null || clientKey.length() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ClientKey is not defined");
        }

        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.mac = getMAC(clientKey);
    }

    public GeocodeResponse geocode(final GeocoderRequest geocoderRequest) throws IOException {

        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();

        final String urlString = getURL(geocoderRequest);

        return request(gson, urlString);

    }

    protected GeocodeResponse request(Gson gson, String urlString) throws IOException {
        final URL url = new URL(urlString);
        final Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), ENCODING));
        try {
            return gson.fromJson(reader, GeocodeResponse.class);
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    }

    public static String getGeocoderHost() {
        return GEOCODE_REQUEST_HOST;
    }

    protected String getURL(final GeocoderRequest geocoderRequest) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        logger.trace("Request {}", geocoderRequest);
        final StringBuilder url = getURLQuery(geocoderRequest);

        if (mac == null) {
            // add server name to URL
            url.insert(0, GEOCODE_REQUEST_SERVER_HTTP);
        } else {
            addClientIdAndSignURL(url);

            // add server name to URL
            url.insert(0, GEOCODE_REQUEST_SERVER_HTTPS);
        }

        logger.trace("FULL Request URL: {}", url);
        return url.toString();
    }

    protected StringBuilder getURLQuery(GeocoderRequest geocoderRequest) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final String channel = geocoderRequest.getChannel();
        final String address = geocoderRequest.getAddress();
        final LatLngBounds bounds = geocoderRequest.getBounds();
        final String language = geocoderRequest.getLanguage();
        final String region = geocoderRequest.getRegion();
        final LatLng location = geocoderRequest.getLocation();
        final EnumMap<GeocoderComponent, String> components = geocoderRequest.getComponents();

        final StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(GEOCODE_REQUEST_QUERY_BASIC);

        if (channel != null && channel.length() > 0) {
            url.append("&channel=").append(URLEncoder.encode(channel, ENCODING));
        }
        if (address != null && address.length() > 0) {
            url.append("&address=").append(URLEncoder.encode(address, ENCODING));
        } else if (location != null) {
            url.append("&latlng=").append(URLEncoder.encode(location.toUrlValue(), ENCODING));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Address or location must be defined");
        }
        if (language != null && language.length() > 0) {
            url.append("&language=").append(URLEncoder.encode(language, ENCODING));
        }
        if (region != null && region.length() > 0) {
            url.append("&region=").append(URLEncoder.encode(region, ENCODING));
        }
        if (bounds != null) {
            url.append("&bounds=").append(URLEncoder.encode(bounds.getSouthwest().toUrlValue() + "|" + bounds.getNortheast().toUrlValue(), ENCODING));
        }
        if (!components.isEmpty()) {
            url.append("&components=");
            boolean isFirstLine = true;
            for (Map.Entry<GeocoderComponent, String> entry : components.entrySet()) {
                if (isFirstLine) {
                    isFirstLine = false;
                } else {
                    url.append(URLEncoder.encode("|", ENCODING));
                }
                url.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey().value(), ENCODING));
                url.append(':');
                url.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), ENCODING));
            }

        }
        logger.trace("URL query: {}", url);
        return url;
    }

    protected void addClientIdAndSignURL(StringBuilder url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        url.append("&client=").append(URLEncoder.encode(clientId, ENCODING));

        logger.trace("URL query to Sign: {}", url);

        byte[] sigBytes;
        synchronized (mac) {
            mac.update(url.toString().getBytes());
            sigBytes = mac.doFinal();
        }

        String signature = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(sigBytes));
        signature = signature.replace('+', '-');
        signature = signature.replace('/', '_');

        if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
            logger.trace("Signature: [{}] for URL query {}", signature, url);
        }
        url.append("&signature=").append(signature);
    }

    protected static Mac getMAC(String clientKey) throws InvalidKeyException {
        try {
            byte[] key = clientKey.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/').getBytes();

            byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decodeBase64(key);

            // Get an HMAC-SHA1 signing key from the raw key bytes
            final SecretKeySpec sha1Key = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, "HmacSHA1");

            // Get an HMAC-SHA1 Mac instance and initialize it with the HMAC-SHA1 key
            final Mac result = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
            result.init(sha1Key);

            return result;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

** The error**

```
2014/12/18 08:46:39,906 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2) I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when processing request: Permission denied
2014/12/18 08:46:39,907 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2) Retrying request
2014/12/18 08:46:39,909 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2) I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when processing request: Permission denied
2014/12/18 08:46:39,912 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2) Retrying request
2014/12/18 08:46:39,914 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2) I/O exception (java.net.BindException) caught when processing request: Permission denied
2014/12/18 08:46:39,917 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2) Retrying request
2014/12/18 08:46:39,938 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2) java.net.BindException: Permission denied
2014/12/18 08:46:39,940 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,943 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,944 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at java.net.Socket.bind(Socket.java:631)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,945 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:423)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,946 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:280)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,947 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,949 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,950 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,951 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,954 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,955 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,956 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,958 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,959 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at com.ndgits.geocoder.AdvancedGeoCoder.request(AdvancedGeoCoder.java:53)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,960 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at com.ndgits.geocoder.Geocoder.geocode(Geocoder.java:73)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,961 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at com.ndgits.rh.services.GeocodingServiceImpl.getAddress(GeocodingServiceImpl.java:65)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,962 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at com.ndgits.rh.web.controller.PersonalInfoController.savePersonalInfo(PersonalInfoController.java:89)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,963 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at com.ndgits.rh.web.controller.PersonalInfoController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$60c8ea34.invoke(<generated>)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,964 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,965 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:701)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,966 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,971 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:51)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,972 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,976 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:55)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,981 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,982 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,983 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,985 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:634)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,989 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at com.ndgits.rh.web.controller.PersonalInfoController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f30f4c6e.savePersonalInfo(<generated>)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,991 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,992 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,993 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,994 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,995 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,996 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,997 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
2014/12/18 08:46:39,999 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,000 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,002 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,003 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,004 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,033 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,034 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,035 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,036 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,037 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,038 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,039 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,041 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,042 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,043 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,044 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,046 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,047 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,048 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,049 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,050 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,051 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,052 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
2014/12/18 08:46:40,053 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.13.128.129-8080-2)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permission denied Error after deploying to Openshift using JBoss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944146/permission-denied-error-after-deploying-to-openshift-using-jboss)

Comment: The error is saying it can't bind to a port on the client side; so it's nothing to do with the URL or proxying - you're not getting that far. See the answers to the question mentioned above.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094918/runtime-java-net-bindexception-by-running-a-spring-application-on-openshift