# Openshift, web service client error: Permission denied

Tags: openshift

Well I have 2 services deployed as a war file in tomcat on Openshift using Jboss. The web services are developped in Eclipse. For testing I have

**The web service:** the function

```
public String sayHello(String input){
     return "Hello "+input; 
}
```

**The client web service**

```
Sayhello sayhello=new Sayhello();
sayhello.setInput("EveryOne");
SayhelloResponse resp= stub.sayhello(sayhello);
String result=resp.get_return();
```

When calling the client web service after it's depled on openshift I got these errors:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Permission denied
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:197)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
    org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
    org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    com.ws.test.HelloAllStub.sayhello(HelloAllStub.java:192)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:87)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Any help is appreciated, my guess is something about port Forwarding ?!